# How to write "#pragma twice" preprocessor in C?

Tags: c

We know there exists `#pragma once` which prevents source file to be included more than once, but how to make preprocessor (with conditional compilation) which prevents the inclusion of the file in another file more than twice (once and twice is possible, but more than doesn't include).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Anything that starts with `#pragma` is handled by a compiler (or ignored) - are you intending to write your own C compiler?

Comment: Construction that leads to the fact that a file saved with it can be included in any other file no more than twice (once and twice possible but no more). It;s a situation when the file we want to include has been already included by another file.

Comment: Can you show a [mre] where `#pragma once` is not sufficient?

Comment: I cannot imagine a situation where this is useful.  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and a big red flag on your architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
// so72049366.h file
#ifndef SO72049366_TWICE

#ifndef SO72049366_ONCE
#define SO72049366_ONCE
#else
#define SO72049366_TWICE
#endif

i++;

#endif
```

---

```
// so72049366.c file
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    #include "so72049366.h"
    printf("%d\n", i);
    #include "so72049366.h"
    printf("%d\n", i);
    #include "so72049366.h"
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

---

Output

```
1
2
2
```